# TSQL procedure by multiple parameters

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am currently in the process of writting a stored procedure and was wondering how to effectively write it based on parameters, if only one is provided.

Pseudocode:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x 
    @p1 datetime = null,
    @p2 int = null,
    @p3 varchar(32) = null

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CASE WHEN @p1 IS NOT NULL THEN
SELECT * FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE T1.data = @p1

WHEN @p2 IS NOT NULL THEN
SELECT * FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.secondID = T3.id
WHERE T1.otherdata = @p2

WHEN @p3 IS NOT NULL THEN
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE T1.thirddata = @p3
END
```

Can I do this with case statements somehow? So when either @p1, @p2 or @p3 is not null, it uses that one? Or do I have to make if/else statements for each of the possibilities (there will only ever be on parameter supplied)? Reason being, I have three input fields on the report, and either can be null, so only one parameter will be supplied, but it searches by different data.

EDIT: Added code to procedure, to clarify what exactly I'm asking (queries join on different tables).

Comment: Here is an excellent site about Dynamic Search Conditions: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis So there is no better way than to do if/else clauses with the same code only different joins?

Comment: Long story short, The answers already provided are fine. But if suddenly you find yourself having tons of variables and complex queries, you might need dynamic sql. The link I gave is very detailed - when you need it it'll be there. For now, I bet Alan's and Zohar's answers will cover you fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Case` is an expression returning a scalar value. You can't use it as a flow control.
This is explicitly stated in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks):

> The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and stored procedures. For a list of control-of-flow methods, see [Control-of-Flow Language (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/control-of-flow?view=sql-server-2017).

Your query can be re-written like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE x 
    @p1 datetime = null,
    @p2 int = null,
    @p3 varchar(32) = null

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE (T1.data = @p1 OR @p1 IS NULL)
AND (T1.otherdata = @p2 OR @p2 IS NULL)
AND (T1.thirddata = @p3 OR @p3 IS NULL)

END
```

There is, however, a problem with this type of stored procedure - SQL Server will use the cached execution plan whenever you run it, and this execution plan might be optimal for one set of parameters but far from optimal for another set of parameters. This can be resolved by using the `recompile` hint, as explained in [Revisiting catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) on SQL in the Wild blog.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to format the query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM T1
    WHERE (data = @p1 or @p1 is null)
        AND (otherdata = @p2 or @p2 is null)
        AND (thirddata = @p3 or @p3 is null)
```